# Designer rehosting questions

Tags: wpf, custom-activity

I am trying to rehost the wf designer inside a wpf window. I have build custom activities and activity designers.

I can't drag and drop onto the workflow custom activity

I don't know how, And I tried alot!!

Thank oyu

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ready to run example:
[Msdn](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wfxbap/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4668)